# Generating array using map functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning functional programming, looking into my code I was just wondering is it possible to do the same thing but using map / reduce function?

Given that I have two values:

```
var firstDate = 1964
var lastDate = 2018
```

I want to get the years in between including itself. I could simply do:

```
var years = [] 

for(var i=firstDate;i<=lastDate;i++)
    years.push(i)

return years
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in a declarative way?
So, I would first create an array with the desired size

```
const years = new Array(lastDate - firstDate)
```

then how can I map the index to each element?

```
years.map((val, i, arr) => ???)
```

Comment: You cannot map an empty array

Comment: `Array(lastDate-firstDate+1).fill(firstDate).map((x, y) => x + y)`